# Android : Fullscreen system visibility screws up window insets

Tags: android, user-interface, android-fragments

I'm writing an app that has one activity and a bunch of fragments and one of those fragments is fullscreen.  In order to achieve that, I'm trying to use the System UI Visibility flags.

For the fullscreen fragment, I set the visibility:

```
layout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

As soon as I do that, the window insets change to values that don't seem to make any sense.  Then, when I exit that fullscreen fragment, I wind up with wrong padding on my view (based on the weird insets)

[image]

Does anyone know what's going on here?  The way I understand the window insets must be wrong, because this behavior seems completely counter intuitive.  Any insight would be appreciated.

To view the full source of the test app I wrote to illustrate the problem go here:

https://github.com/dapp/visibilitytest

Comment: There were a few other things I'd fix in your visiblitytest project that didn't affect the insets problem: your `systemUiVisile` defaulted to `true` even though you hide the system UI in `onCreateView()` (should probably be `false`), you should hide the action bar in `onCreateView()` to be consistent with the button, you should reset the systemUI/action bar in `onDestroyView()`, and you should [respond to UI visibility changes](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/visibility.html) to ensure your action bar stays in sync with the UI visiblity.

Comment: I don't hide the system ui in the onCreateView, rather, I set the layout of the fragment to 

`View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION`

Which only tells the view to layout *as though* the system ui were hidden.  I don't actually hide the system ui until the button is clicked.  Thats why systemUiVisible defaults to true.

Comment: Calling setSystemUiVisibility() from any attached layout is identical (note the comment on [the training sample](http://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/dim.html#dim)) in that it immediately sets the system UI visibility - calling it on an unattached view is the source of your problem.

Comment: I'm not say that isn't the problem, I'm just saying that your comment that I'm hiding the system ui in the onCreateView isn't technically correct.  I don't hide the system ui in the onCreateView, I merely set the layout to fullscreen.  I'll comment on your solution in the answer section.

Comment: Ah, you changed your code - your original code was *not* using the `LAYOUT` flags.

Comment: I'm not sure if we're looking at the same code.  Please see my latest 2 comment2 in the answer section.

Comment: @Dapp: Facing similar issue did you gets answer. I also tried your github commit "cbf0943d091cefa7ed4bc82a059a181cec40bd4b" but it didn't work for me.

Comment: RIght... the point of the Github project was just to illustrate the problem.   There does not appear to be a solution.  I would suggest that you take the fullscreen components of your app and just make them into their own activity.  Changing the visibility with Fragments doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem today. I am using a NavigationView from design library. When I exit full screen, there are insects on top and bottom of NavigationView, which is ugly.

I debug and dig into the source code of NavigationView and find following solution:

1. Please use setFitsSystemWindows(false) method for your view, in my case, for NavigationView, to avoid impact of status bar and navigation bar changes.
2. I found there is OnApplyWindowInsetsListener in NavigationView's super class: ScrimInsetsFrameLayout, then I clear this listener to avoid impact when full screen is enabled/disabled, by using ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(mNavigationView, null).

Now the NavigationView behaves correctly when exit full screen, hope this helps for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

`setSystemUiVisibility()` propagates the system UI visibility changes up the view hierarchy (to request new insets).

However, when you call `layout.setSystemUiVisibility()` in your Fragment's `onCreateView()`, the `layout` is not yet attached to the view hierarchy. This is what causes your issues with the insets not being updated appropriately.

You can instead call `getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility()` in `onCreateView()` and you'll find that all insets work correctly.

Comment: So, I believe I've followed your instructions exactly, but I still wind up with some strange behavior.  When I load the fullscreen fragment, toggle it to full screen and back, and then hit the back button, I get this:

http://imgur.com/m5HDl7F

I updated the code on Github.

Comment: Your previous code was using `layout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);` in your `onCreateView()`, which you have since changed to using the `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION` flags - removing the now added `LAYOUT` flags from where you added them fixes the issue. What exactly are you trying to do in that line?

Comment: Are you talking about the change to line 23 in onCreateVew?  Because I'm looking at the diff and it reads:

`layout.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
 +        getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);`

The flags haven't changed, only the view that's calling the `setSystemUiVisibility` has changed.

Comment: What I'm trying to do there, is layout the fragment fullscreen, underneath the status bar, action bar and nav bar.   Then when I remove that fragment, I want the previous fragment/activity to return to a non-fullscreen layout, with its layout appropriately adjusted to the normal insets for status bar, action bar and nav bar.