# NavigationView weird spacing for support library 23.2.0

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am using Navigation drawer under the App bar for an app. All was working well till support library v23.1.1. Once updated to 23.2.0, the `NavigationView` shows a weird semi transparent top padding. The behaviour seems related to `fitsSystemWindows` attribute, and this space is looking like the one designed for the status bar shade.

Sample repository [here](https://github.com/mihirtech/SampleDrawer)

Can anybody help fix this behaviour for support library v23.2.0

[image: Nav_view_with_header_23_2_0]
[image: Nav_view_with_header_23_1_1]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Remove the attribute `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from you activity. This will remove the space on below the toolbar.
As it is said in this [blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.uccnl291f) the `fitsSystemWindows`attribute sets a padding "to ensure the contents don’t overlay the system windows".

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: another SO user posted a work-around that seems to address the issue:
[Android : Fullscreen system visibility screws up window insets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445535/android-fullscreen-system-visibility-screws-up-window-insets/36751650#36751650)

---

I've been facing the same issue. In my app, we switch the full screen UI flags on and off, depending on the content the user is viewing.  Changing the UI flags actually breaks the NavigationView even worse, adding that shaded overlay to the top and bottom of the nav drawer.

I forked your gitHub example and added the ability to change the UI flags. You can see my fork here: https://github.com/mnkyby78/SampleDrawer

I also opened a ticket on code.google.com: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231376

I haven't found any solutions yet.  My app is currently stuck using Support Library 23.1.1 until Google fixes this.